# Ionic 2 execute method when user leaves the app

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to execute a method when the user leaves the app. I tried everything:

```
ionViewWillUnload() {
  console.log("Wlill unload");
  this.leaveRoom();
}

onDestroy() {
  console.log("DESTROY");
  this.leaveRoom();
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.leaveRoom();
}
```

Unfortunetly they are not executed when user closes the app or when the user refresh the page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Import Platform:

   `import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';`
2. Add Platform to the constuctor:

   `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform)`
3. subscribe to the platform `pause` and `resume`:

   ```
        platform.ready().then(() => {
           this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
               console.log('[INFO] App paused');
           });

           this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
               console.log('[INFO] App resumed');
           });
       });
   ```

Comment: upVote/ downVote, mark Resolved/mark Unresolved and now you Answer yourself, what's next? And you're just using the methods i mentioned.

Comment: I marked it as resolved because I though it works, but it doesn't. you need to subscribe to the platform pause and resume. Instead of editing all your answer, i created new one

Comment: the "pause" event does not appear to fire on IOS when the app is shut down. only when it is put in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for can be found here:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#endcallbutton

Specifically this event:

```
function onEndCallKeyDown() {
    // Handle the end call button
}
```

In order to make the event work you have to declare this listener first:

```
document.addEventListener("endcallbutton", onEndCallKeyDown, false);
```

**onPause Event:**

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
}
```

**onResume event**

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This event supports only `blackberry10`.

Comment: I edited the answer, now it points to the actual cordova version.

Comment: @TheUnreal Here you have the list of the supported platforms updated for the new version: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/support/index.html

Comment: The solution does't do the trick, even after I tried to declare the listener first

Comment: If this event doesn't work, then try onResume and onPause. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `pause` happens when the user send the app to background, I need to run a method when the user totally closes the app

Comment: @TheUnreal and what does the documentation say about closing the app and having an event fired? or are you solely relying on answers giving here without visiting documentation?

Comment: AFAIK, pause is called when you're about to close an application because it first goes to the background and when you swipe to close it out of your list of open applications, it closes.

Comment: If I could find my answer in the docs, I wouldn't bother to write here. Couldn't find any answer on google too. Seem like the solution is to use `pause()` although the user may not close the app.

Comment: use ``platform.pause``